# Inner join multiple csv files with python

Tags: python, csv

I have a directory containing 10K csv files. Each file has 2 columns and column 1 is same across all files.

I want to inner join all files based on column 1 and get a final output as shown in snippet below

```
#Original data of different csv files

#file1.csv
id,A
1,a1
2,a2
3,a3

#file2.csv
id,B
1,b1
2,b2
3,b3

#file3.csv
id,C
1,c1
2,c2
3,c3

#Final Output after using python script with glob pattern to operate on all csv files in a directory
id,A,B,C
1,a1,b1,c1
2,a2,b2,c2
3,a3,b3,c3
```

I am using linux and wanted to know a fast/efficient way to achieve this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I don't know the fastest or efficient way to achieve this, but you'll have to use `pandas`. Just read the doc and you'll be there. This might help: https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html

Comment: maybe give this a try: http://harelba.github.io/q/ - not affiliated in anyway

Answer (score 0):

I tried 2 approaches to the above problem

1. [csvtk](https://bioinf.shenwei.me/csvtk/) - absolutely great tool for csv/tsv data munging
2. python script

My dataset:

```
 - 16,000 files - each file has 2 columns and 1000 rows
 - Column 1 of each file is the same as mentioned in the original post
```

**csvtk approach**

```
my_var=$(ls -1v *csv |  perl -pe 's#\n# #g')

time csvtk join -f1 $my_var > file_merge_csvtk_join.csv

real    41m37.707s
user    196m47.658s
sys     1m6.516s
```

**python approach**

```
time python join_csvs_on_column1.py  file_merge_with_python_pandas.csv

real    0m48.852s
user    0m0.024s
sys     0m0.034s
```

**python script**

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# scriptName: join_csvs_on_column1.py

import pandas as pd
import glob
import os
import sys

output_file = sys.argv[1]

path = os.getcwd()

filenames = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
dfs = [pd.read_csv(filename, index_col=0) for filename in filenames]

result = dfs[0].join(dfs[1:])

result.to_csv(output_file)
```

Both the above tests were done on:

```
m5.2xlarge EC2 - https://aws.amazon.com/ec2/instance-types/

 - it has 8vCPUs and 32 GiB Memory
```